# How to search for UIView inside many levels of UIViews?

Tags: ios

Is there a better way to search for UIViews children inside 3-4+ levels of UIViews without using tag? Is there a much better way to go directly into the child UIView without having to traverse the tree every time? The tag is really not helping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access a view directly you may use

```
[randomChildView.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0]
```

in order to avoid looping all subviews you can use of enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

```
- (NSArray*) allSubviews {
     __block NSArray* allSubviews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self];
     [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^( UIView* view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL*stop) {  
         allSubviews = [allSubviews arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[view allSubviews]];
     }];
    return allSubviews;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to do get UIViewD that's under: UIViewA->UIViewB->UIViewC->UIViewD in one line of code.

Comment: is it under or nested?

Comment: All the views are nested.

Comment: yes u can using [UIViewA.subviews objectAtIndex:[UIViewA.subviews count]-1];

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant.